# PostgreSQL 9.6 Master on CentOS, Replica On Ubuntu?

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

I know it isn't ideal, but I'm wondering if there are any limitations preventing me from having a downstream replica be on Ubuntu (xenial), while its upstream replica is on CentOS?

I've got postgresql installed on the Ubuntu box and plan to set the $PGDATA dir and all of those settings the same as the CentOS boxes.

I'm just curious of anyone has tried this and run into any snags.

Comment: The Postgres versions matter, the OS can be different

Comment: @mike.k That is a dangerous misconception, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle that would work as long as both Linuxen are running on the same architecture. But read [this mailing list post](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CB4D1C6BAA80CF146CB0D4F2%40eje.credativ.lan) for an example of what can go wrong:

PostgreSQL uses the operating system's collations for ordering indexes, and if the two versions of glibc installed on both machines have a different idea of how to order strings, the indexes on string columns will be corrupted on the standby.

So if you need to replicate across distributions, make sure that one of the following applies:

- You are using the C collation.
- All indexes on string columns in your database are using the `text_pattern_ops` operator class.
- You have the same version of glibc on both machines.

Comment: The existing master and replicas already have `lc_collate=en_US.UTF-8`. My understanding is you can't change that.

It's a safe bet that *none* of our string indexes use anything other than the default classes, so likely won't be many, if any, `text_pattern_ops` classes in use (although learning about them now was a good TIL).

The existing master/replicas are on CentOS 7 and 6. CentOS 7 uses glibc 2.17, where CentOS6 uses glibc 2.12. The ubuntu box (xenial LTS) has libc6 2.23. Is there a way to test for changes that would make the replica incompatible?

Comment: Note that `text_pattern_ops` is *safe* and *the default is unsafe*. Different glibc versions are bad news, though I don't know if there are many differences for English. I don't know a test for that. I recommend using identical machines throughout.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thank you for pointing out that post, very interesting